# hibernate session.get return null

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-session

I have such code:

```
Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.sessionFactory.openSession();

    System.out.println("------------------" + session.get(User.class, (long) 10));
    System.out.println("------------------" + session.createSQLQuery("SELECT  * FROM  diploma.tbl_users Where id = 10").addEntity(User.class).uniqueResult());
```

First row return null.
The second return valid record.

But  if I change places:

```
System.out.println("------------------" + session.createSQLQuery("SELECT  * FROM  diploma.tbl_users Where id = 10").addEntity(User.class).uniqueResult());
    System.out.println("------------------" + session.get(User.class, (long) 10));
```

Both rows return correct result:

This is my hibernate session factory:

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

public static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")
        .buildSessionFactory();

 }
```

Why `session.get(User.class, (long) 10))` return null ?

**UPDATE**
hibernate config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diploma</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>

    .........................................
    <mapping class="edu.test.entities.User" />
            ..................................

</session-factory>
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_Users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "Surname")
private String surname;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "Login")
private String login;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min=6, max=20)
@Column(name = "Password")
private String password;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "Email")
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "Phone")
private String phone;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Role", nullable = false)
private Roles role;

    // getters and setters
```

Id field from base entity

```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {    
    @Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

**UPDATE 2**
  The problem was in mapping file `@JoinColumn(name = "Role", nullable = false)
    private Roles role;` I have specified that Role cannot be null and the record that I have tried to retrieve with id 10 have null Role foreign key. So I change  `nullable = true` and it works.

Comment: what is the primary key for the entity class?

Comment: @Arun how you expect to get the entity before adding it?

Comment: what did you mean  'you try to get entity before saving.' saving what ?

Comment: @Lemberg I confused registering the entity and saving it )))

Comment: @Lemberg Can you share `hibernate.cfg.xml` and the mapping file

Comment: Also it would be nice to see the resulting SQL query that hibernate generates when you call `.get()`

Comment: Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id7_1_,
        user0_.Email as Email7_1_,
        user0_.Login as Login7_1_,
        user0_.Name as Name7_1_,
        user0_.Password as Password7_1_,
        user0_.Phone as Phone7_1_,
        user0_.Role as Role7_1_,
        user0_.Surname as Surname7_1_,
        roles1_.id as id6_0_,
        roles1_.RoleName as RoleName6_0_ 
    from
        tbl_Users user0_ 
    inner join
        tbl_Roles roles1_ 
            on user0_.Role=roles1_.id 
    where
        user0_.id=?

Comment: @Lemberg are you sure that your user row in the database have the Role attached?

Comment: In other words, check that the role row exist for the user with id 10.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov thanks for help the trouble was with record with id 10 it has reference to role table null, when I try to get record with existing Role foreing key it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate implements [Identity Map PoEAA pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern), where the Hibernate session plays the role of the map. When you call `.addEntity()`, the loaded entities become associated with the Hibernate session.

Then when you call Hibernate session's get method it first checks the entity cache and returns a existing entity if present.

So in the first statement when you call `get` the entity is not yet present in the entity map. In the second snippet the entity is being cached with `.addEntity()` method.

**update** So the problem is that reference to the role is declared with `nullable = false`, and there's no such a role in the database.

See also: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html

Comment: you are saying that in the first row it returns null because the User entity is not declared in the hibernate.cfg file, right?

Comment: Not quite, in this code the entity is registered manually in hibernate session with the query, ok. I'll update the answer then.

Comment: I agree that retrieving single instance with SQL is not right choice I want to do this with session.get() but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Lemberg How is the `id` database field mapped in your class(where is the java field)?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov Can you tell me if I can retrieve User from DB with null reference to Roles?

Comment: Try setting `nullable` to true